# How to visit URL multiple times with different parameters in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the parse function as :

```
def parse(self,response):
    a = list(map(chr, range(97,123)))
    for i in a:
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata = {'posted':'posted', 'LastName':i, 'distance':'0', 'current_page':'2'},
            callback = self.after
        )
```

Here I am sending requests to same URL but with different LastName parameter as shown above. But it is not returning response to all my requests. Instead it only retrieves the result for letter 'Q'. How to force it to visit same URL with different parameter each time?

Comment: can you share your console output? (with LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG (default))

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `dont_filter = True` on your `FormRequest`.

```
yield FormRequest.from_response(
    response,
    formdata = {'posted':'posted', 'LastName':i, 'distance':'0', 'current_page':'2'},
    callback = self.after,
    dont_filter=True
)
```

See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html for more info about it.

Comment: I have done so but it now only issues requests for 2 letters in the whole list of alphabets. Why is it so? It should have 26 requests (the number of alphabets stored in the list) and as accordingly 26 responses.

Comment: Could you add the log to your question and if possible, the url of the site you're scraping?